# Отправка данных через CURL

Tags: php, база-данных, curl

У меня есть форма заполнения, там есть поля ФИО,email, мобильный телефон и.т.д, когда нажимаю на сабмит она должна отправлять эти формы на БД

```
<?php 
 $url = "GetClientESD";
 $api=new api();
    print_r( $api->sendrequest($url));



    class api {
function sendrequest($url){  



   $host= 'http://192.168.233.206:71/';



$this->apiurl=$host."api/v1ogpo/";



      $url=$this->apiurl.$url;
 //echo $url;

    $sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$this->str2url($url).date('U'), hash('sha256', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], true));
 $id=111;



$ch = curl_init();
 $post = array('payload' => '1');



 if (isset($this->post) ){
//echo "<div style='display:none;'>";
//print_r($this->post);
//echo "</div>";
foreach ($this->post as $key => $value) {
  $this->post[$key]=trim($value);
}

 $options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_POST =>1,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>
            $this->post,
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
    'sign: '.$sign.'', 'id: '.$id

));

 }
 else {
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    CURLOPT_URL => $url,

     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
    'sign: '.$sign.'', 'id: '.$id

));
    }
curl_setopt_array($ch , $options);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<div style='display:none;'>".$output."</div>" ;
if(!$output)
{
    return array( 'err'=>"Curl Error : Ошибка доступа к сервису1"); //curl_error($ch));
}
else
{   
//


//$arr=array();
$arr=json_decode($output, true);


    if (count($arr)){
   return  json_decode($output, true);}
   else return array( 'err'=>"Ошибка доступа к сервису");

}




  }




  function rus2translit($string) {
    $converter = array(
        'а' => 'a',   'б' => 'b',   'в' => 'v',
        'г' => 'g',   'д' => 'd',   'е' => 'e',
        'ё' => 'e',   'ж' => 'zh',  'з' => 'z',
        'и' => 'i',   'й' => 'y',   'к' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l',   'м' => 'm',   'н' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o',   'п' => 'p',   'р' => 'r',
        'с' => 's',   'т' => 't',   'у' => 'u',
        'ф' => 'f',   'х' => 'h',   'ц' => 'c',
        'ч' => 'ch',  'ш' => 'sh',  'щ' => 'sch',
        'ь' => '\'',  'ы' => 'y',   'ъ' => '\'',
        'э' => 'e',   'ю' => 'yu',  'я' => 'ya',

        'А' => 'A',   'Б' => 'B',   'В' => 'V',
        'Г' => 'G',   'Д' => 'D',   'Е' => 'E',
        'Ё' => 'E',   'Ж' => 'Zh',  'З' => 'Z',
        'И' => 'I',   'Й' => 'Y',   'К' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L',   'М' => 'M',   'Н' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O',   'П' => 'P',   'Р' => 'R',
        'С' => 'S',   'Т' => 'T',   'У' => 'U',
        'Ф' => 'F',   'Х' => 'H',   'Ц' => 'C',
        'Ч' => 'Ch',  'Ш' => 'Sh',  'Щ' => 'Sch',
        'Ь' => '\'',  'Ы' => 'Y',   'Ъ' => '\'',
        'Э' => 'E',   'Ю' => 'Yu',  'Я' => 'Ya'
    );
    return strtr($string, $converter);
}
function str2url($str) {
    // переводим в транслит
    $str = $this->rus2translit($str);
    // в нижний регистр
    $str = strtolower($str);
     $str = str_replace('%20', '', $str);
    // заменяем все ненужное нам на "-"
    $str = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9_.]+~u', '', $str);
    // удаляем начальные и конечные '-'
    $str = trim($str, "-");
    return $str;
}


}
?>
```

это api к которому я должен подключиться, как можно с помощью этого api реализовать отправку формы в БД?

Comment: Если у Вас, что то не работает с rest api, то воспользуйтесь к примеру такой программой как https://www.getpostman.com/. Проверьте все (притом программа генерирует код даже к php), а после задавайте вопрос